# Parallel programming in gfortran, strange? result in hello program

Tags: fortran, cygwin, openmp, gfortran

I compile the next hello program, but I don't get the result that I may expect.

```
program hello

print*, " Hello parallel world"

!$omp parallel

print*, omp_get_thread_num()

!$omp end parallel

print*, "Back to the sequential world"

end
```

---

To compile I use:

`mpifort -fopenmp -o hello hello.f90`

---

When I run it, it results:

```
Hello parallel world

0.00000000

0.00000000

0.00000000

0.00000000

Back to the sequential world
```

---

, but according to a manual (Parallel Programming in OpenMP by Rohit Chandra, Ramesh Menon, Leo Dagum, David Kohr, Dror Maydan, Jeff McDonald) I could get numbers between 0 and 3, not only zeros. There is something wrong?

Comment: First you should try a pure OpenMP program (e.g. no mpi). Then add `use omp_lib` and `implicit none` at the beginning of your program, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `use omp_lib` and the compiler implicitly assumes that `omp_get_num_thread()` is a function that returns a floating-point value, because its name begins with `o`. It is not though - it returns an `integer`. Adding `implicit none` right after `program hello` will turn off implicit declarations and trigger a compile-time error without `use omp_lib`.

```
program hello
   use omp_lib
   implicit none
   print*, "Hello parallel world"
!$omp parallel
   print*, omp_get_thread_num()
!$omp end parallel
   print*, "Back to the sequential world"
end
```

Comment: `implicit none` causes compiling error. Without it, it compiles and works fine

Comment: My bad, `implicit none` should come after `use`, not before.

Comment: Thank you everyone, that fix it.